# Windows Powershell - extract multiline text between two words from a text file

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a text file contents of which look like

```
Information Submitted:

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From:   
Sent:   
To: 
Subject:    


zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Information Submitted:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From:   
Sent:   
To: 
Subject:    


zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Information Submitted:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From:   
Sent:   
To: 
Subject:
```

I want to extract the content between each occurence of "Information Submitted:" and "From:" which is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

please let me know if i can do this in poweshell.

thank you

sasi

Comment: This can definately be done. What have you tried so far? SO works better if you show us some initial effort.

Comment: I tried doing this  $str = Get-Content .\GoPaperLessTShirts_113mails_may2014.txt | out-string
 $start = $str.IndexOf("Information Submitted:")+1
 $end = $str.IndexOf("From:",$start)
 $length = $end - $start
 $str.Substring($start,$length) but it gives me only the top occurrence but i need all the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a multi-line regex solution:

```
@'
Information Submitted:

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From:   
Sent:   
To: 
Subject:    


zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Information Submitted:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From:   
Sent:   
To: 
Subject:    


zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Information Submitted:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

From:   
Sent:   
To: 
Subject:
'@ | Set-Content testfile.txt




[regex]$regex = 
@'
(?ms)Information Submitted:
(.+?)
From:.+?   
'@

$regex.Matches("$(Get-Content testfile.txt -Raw)") |
 foreach { $_.groups[1].value }



xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```